# MonoRail File Upload

Tags: castle-monorail

I don't suppose anyone's clued up on this? The documentation is *terrible* and far outdated (the best resource I could find was dated 2006).

My form:

```
<form action="DoCreate.rails" method="post">

    ${FormHelper.LabelFor("master.Name", "Name", {"class":"label"})}
    ${FormHelper.TextField("master.Name", {"class":"text-input full-width"})}

    ${FormHelper.LabelFor("masterFile", "File", {"class":"label"})}
    <input type="file" id="masterFile" name="masterFile" />

    <div class="edit-controls"><a href="/Master/Index.rails">Back</a> | <input type="submit" value="Create" /></div>
</form>
```

My controller action:

```
    public void DoCreate(Master master, HttpPostedFile masterFile)
    {
        try
        {
            Bus.Master.Create(master);

            if (masterFile != null)
            {
                masterFile.SaveAs(@"C:\" + masterFile.FileName);
            }

            RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (ApplicationException e)
        {
            PropertyBag["error"] = e.Message + "<br />" + e.StackTrace;
            Create();
            RenderView("Create");
        }
    }
```

I followed [this guide](http://www.kenegozi.com/Blog/2008/06/28/filebinderattribute-to-ease-fileupload-in-monorail.aspx) also with no avail as it doesn't tell you what to do on the actual HTML page.

Comment: I am missing the actual question here. What is the problem here?

as a side note, it is not recommended to render a view as a result of a POST call. This will mess with the user's browsing history. It is better to redirect (in your case to the "Create" action) so that the user's browser will issue a new GET request for the webpage with the form.

Comment: Sorry, the actual issue is that the upload doesn't work, I wasn't sure what the HTML page is supposed to include as MonoRail appear to have got rid of the file upload helper.  If I attempt to call that, I get the error "Could not convert param as the node related to the param is not a leaf node. Param master parent node: root".

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem is with the declaration of the form.
When uploading files, you should use add another attribute to the form element: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`